# migrate data from mysql5.1 to mysql5.6

Tags: mysql, dbmigrate

i want to migrate data from mysql5.1 to mysql5.6. i installed mysql5.6 successfully but i have data of older version is more than 50 GB. i want to just copy and paste in newer version. i did it but some table does not accessible.

i guess it is problem of engine(**innodb/myisam**) for table but i don't know how to solve it.

i found another problem when alter the table it gives error "table is full."

How can I create separate table-space for each table without loss of any data?

Answer (score 0):

Dump all your database/tables/data using mysqldump from 5.1

Then you simply reimport it in the new 5.6 version.

Do you have workbench or do you use the command promt? In workbench there is a migration wizrd. However, since your dbase is more than 50 GB i would strongly recommend dumping the data and then reimporting it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html -This link will help you out.